# How to send a json text with event.respond in Telethon

Tags: python, json, telegram, telethon

I'm making a tool with Telethon in Python. My code is

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

client = TelegramClient(session=session, api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
bot = client.start(bot_token=bot_token)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))

bot.connect()

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))
async def start(event):
    await event.respond(str({'hi': 'hi, 'hello': 'hello'}))
```

I run code and the message result is `{'hi': 'hi, 'hello': 'hello'}`

Now I want to send text that the output likes json, such as:

```
{
    'hi': 'hi, 

    'hello': 'hello'
}
```

How can I do for this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To pretty-format JSON, you should use the [built-in JSON module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). It has the method to **dump** a **s**tring with indentation:

```py
import json

...

your_dict = {'hi': 'hi', 'hello': 'hello'}
your_json = json.dumps(your_dict, indent=4)
await event.respond(your_json)
```

However, I recommend you wrap the JSON in a `<pre>` block to preserve formatting:

```py
import html

...

await event.respond(f'<pre>{your_json}</pre>', parse_mode='html')
```